# Not-only Network database (desktop app) - Document oriented

Tags: c++, database, document-database

I'm looking for a database that provides access as SQLite or BerkeleyDB do: access through "in-process API calls". That would be for use in a desktop application.

Requirements:

- can be linked to the desktop application (no separate process/server to be run)
- document oriented, with query-able metadata/fields
- indexing
- persistent (disk storage)
- C++ bindings

Comment: Why not use one of the DBs you mentioned?

Comment: I would prefer a schema-less DB for holding documents/entries. Each document has metadata fields + a "large" binary field (from a few kB to 5 GB: sensor data signal). I could use a combination of sqlite (for metadata) + regular files for the binary fields but consistency is not guaranteed (e.g.: if the user deletes some data files).

Comment: What have you found out already? And why do those findings not apply for you?

Comment: I looked at [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) and seemed to be a framework to create database software and to be key-value oriented. However, @eandersson in an answer below suggests EJDB whose built on top of Tokyo Cabinet. EJDB is promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many alternatives, but I think that it will be difficult to find an database that meets your exact requirments

Some of the alternatives that comes to mind are [HamsterDB](http://hamsterdb.com/about), [EJDB](http://ejdb.org/) and [FireBird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/). These can all be embedded into your application and provides C++ bindings.

Comment: EJDB is the way to go, even if it is a young project. Its foundations are solid (Tokyo Cabinet based and mongodb philosophy). Moreover, its license, LGPL, perfectly fits my needs. Thanks @eandersson!

Comment: Glad to hear that you found your solution. :)